# What is the location / path of the finder icons?

Tags: macos, finder

What's the location (path) of these icons/buttons for **OSX Lion**? what is the width, height? What is it called? Finder Icon or Finder Button ?

[image: Sample image]

Comment: The third one is from Dropbox actually...

Comment: i am asking their physical locations (posix path) not their names...

Answer (score 1):

These icons are located at:

> /System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/

Comment: `/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources`

Answer (score 1):

They are located in an Apple Asset Catalog proprietary .car archive format at:

> /System/Library/CoreServices/SystemAppearance.bundle/Contents/Resources/Assets.car

There are also other .car files in that folder with icon images for various system display settings.

You can browse and export images from the Assets.car file by using the AssetCatalogTinkerer tool:

https://github.com/insidegui/AssetCatalogTinkerer